# How to remove duplicity from array of dictionaries in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

```
  (
    {
            color = blue;
    },
    {
            color = blue;
    },
    {
            color = red;
    },
    {
            color = white;
    }
 )
```

This is an Array of dictionary, i have to remove duplicate dictionary from array corresponding to key color.

Comment: Just for clarfivation. These two blues are those the same instance of the same object or are those different instances which happen to have the same value?

Comment: Both are different objects which have same values, actually it is easy to remove duplicity from simple array, here i faced problem because array contained dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSSet` is to save you in this case. Use:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:duplicateArray];
NSArray *uniqueArray = [set allObjects];
```

Avoid using loop for this because if you have more object loop is a consuming process. You can directly use `NSSet` and it will work for sure.

Comment: This approach only applies if the dictionaries only contain the single key (or all dictionaries with the same color value match each other).

Comment: @Wain is correct. Take a look at My answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17379211/1603072. It will work for any number of Keys.

Comment: This, too, only works if the two "blue" objects refer to an identical instance. An NSSEt can very well hold a number of instances that carry the same values.

Comment: @Wain and @Vin If you have more than one keys in dictionary and array has two dictionary with same key-value than also `NSSet` will work and I think that is what called duplicate object if two objects have same value.

Comment: I've just checked it and, NSSet is really amazing, i thought it wont work with array of dictionary. But it does, Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Working Code :**

```
NSArray *html = @[@{@"color": @("blue")},@{@"color": @("blue")},@{@"color": @("red")},@{@"color": @("yellow")}];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableSet *mainSet = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSDictionary *item in html) {
    //Extract the part of the dictionary that you want to be unique:
    NSDictionary *dict = [item dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"color"]];
    if ([mainSet containsObject:dict]) {
        continue;
    }
    [mainSet addObject:dict];
    [finalArray addObject:item];
}
NSLog(@"%@", finalArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Vin's solution which I believe would work. But this one does not create a resulting array. It manipulates the existing one. For doing so it creates temporary copies to drive the iterations.

```
NSArray workingCopy = [NSArray arrayWithArray:yourArray];

for (int i = 0; i < [workingCopy count] - 1; i++) { // count - 1 just saves time. Works nicely without.

  for (int j = i+1; j < [workingCopy count]; j++) {

    if ([[[workingCopy objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"color"] isEqualToString: [[workingCopy objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"color"]] {

       [yourArray removeOjbect:[[workingCopy objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"color"]] // yourArray must be mutable for this. 
    }      
  }
}
```

This algo creates a copy of the original array before. That is to avoid hasseling with changes to the very array that is used for iterations/enumerations. Then it iterates though the copy in a 2-dimensional loop by avoiding to compare the same object with itself (i is never qual to j) and it avoids compaing A with B when B was already compared with A. Both is achieved by stating the j loop with i+1. 
The very last iteration would be `i = [workingCopy count]`. Then `j` would start off with `i+1` and therefore already be larger than `[workingCopy count]`. The loop's body would not be executed a single time. That's why the `i` loop can already finish with `[workingCopy count] - 1`.

The same can be achieved without a copy of the original array. But that does require rather smart manipulations of the running idices i and j, which is no good programming style, rather complex and error prone.

Answer (score -1):

if arr is the array from which you want to remove duplicates

> ```
> for(int index = 0;index<arr.count;index++){
>     NSDictionary *dict = [arr objectAtIndex:index];
>     for(int i = index-1 ; i>=0 ;i++){
>         NSDictionary *dictToComp = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
>         if([[dict objectForKey:@"color"] isEqualToString:[dictToComp objectForKey:@"color"]]){
>             [arr removeObject:dict];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thats not gonna work for two reasons. First you will have to change that `i++` to `i--` if you don't want to mess up with the array indices. (if you did not use it as index then you will not even get an aboort but an infinite loop there). Second by removing objects from `arr` itself you will mess up your algorithm, skip iterations and end up with an illegal idex abort anyway.